# I need help understanding how to write a proof. Time sensitive.

Tags: proof-writing

Let A, B and C be sets. Show that it is always true that
A \ (B \ C) ⊆ (A \ B) ∪ C.
Give an example of specific sets A, B and C to show that it is not necessarily true that A \ (B \ C) = (A \ B) ∪ C.

I don't know where to start and I have never written a proof before.

I have tried:
Let x be an element of A \ (B \ C).
By the definition of set difference, we have:
x is an element of A and x is not an element of (B \ C)

I don't know if this is right or not. If it is right, where do I go from there. If not, how do I do this proof? My professor is not teaching this class face to face. All he is giving us is notes that we copy. No videos or conference calls at all.

Thanks!

Comment: you're right so far $x\in A$ and $x \not \in B\setminus C$.  Go further.  can $x$ be in $B$ ?  in $C$.  if so, under what circumstances? If $x$ *is* in $B$ then as $x\not \in B\setminus C$ so $x$ must be in $C$.   But if $x$ isn't in $B$ then $x\in A\setminus B$.

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to make a picture...

[image]

Now can you describe in words what the picture shows?

Every element of $A (\backslash B\backslash C)$ is also a member of $(A \backslash B) \cup C$

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to break into cases and say something such as "Either $x$ is an element of $B$... or  it isnt".

So if $x \in A\setminus (B\setminus C)$ then $x$ is in $A$.  And $x$ is not in $B\setminus C$.

Now $x \in A$ and either $x \in B$ or .... it isn't.  If $x$ is not in $B$ then $x \in A\setminus B$.

And if $x$ *is* in $B$ then we also have $x$ is *not* in $B\setminus C$.  So *IF* $x \in B$ but not in $B\setminus C$ then $x$ can not be excluded excluded for $C$ (because that would mean $x$ *is* in $B\setminus C$.  So *if* $x \in B$ then $x \in C$.

so if $x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)$ then *either* $x \in A \setminus B$  *or* $x \in C$

so $x \in (A\setminus B)\cup C$.

.....

Now for an example $A\setminus (B\setminus C)\ne (A\setminus B) \cup C$ simply note, that if $x \in A\setminus (B\setminus C)$ then $x$ must be in $A$.  But if $y\in (A\setminus B) \cup C$ we don't need $y$ to be in $A$-- we could have $y\in C$.

Let $A,B,C$ but *any* sets where there is a $y\in C\setminus A$.  Then $y\not \in A\setminus (B\setminus C)$ but $y \in (A\setminus B) \cup C$.

For a simple example let $C = \{y,1,2,3\}$ and $A=\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{y,2,4,w,z\}$.  (I pretty much made those up off the top of my head; the only thing I *needed* was $y\in C$ but $y\not \in A$.  I *could* have chosen $C= \{y\}; A=\emptyset; B=\emptyset$.  That would make for a more *basic* example; but I don't think it'd be as *illustrative* example).

Then $A \setminus (B\setminus C) = A\setminus \{y,4,w,z\}=\{2,3,4,5\}\setminus \{y,4,w,z\}= \{2,3,5\}$.

But $(A\setminus B)\cup C =\{3,5\} \cup C = \{3,5\} \cup \{y,1,2,3\} =  \{y,1,2,3,5\}$.

Notice that $\{2,3,5\} \subset \{y,1,2,5\}$ but $\{2,3,5\} \ne \{y,1,2,5\}$